# Can you access fields of a subclass which are not declared in the superclass?

Tags: scala, inheritance

So i have an absract superclass, and a subclass that extends this superclass with fields that are not declared in the superclass. Is there a way to access those fields from within the superclass? I can't declare these fields in the superclass because it has other subclases which may not have these fields.

> **Edit** in order to make it clearer:

So i am making some kind of shop which has different items. Thus i have an abstract class called item (with a field: price) and the different items are object which extend the item class an define the price. But there are also some special items where all the instances of the same item have different id's, they also declare their price. And a "shopper" must be able to make a "shopping list" of items both normal and special ones, where the total price can be calculated but you must also be able to see the id's of the special items from within the list.

> **Edit**: an example of what i want to achieve.

I made a little example

```
//The numbers are different for each ticket
// and are used to denote a winner in the end.
abstract class LotteryTicket(val numbers: String) {
  val price: Int
}

class GoldTicket(numbers: String) extends LotteryTicket(person) {
  val price: Int = 10
}

class SilverTicket(numbers: String) extends LotteryTicket(person) {
  val price: Int = 5
}

abstract class Drink {
  val price: Int
}

object Water extends Drink {
  val price: Int = 1
}

object Coffee extends Drink {
  val price: Int = 2
}

class Bill

class Customer
```

The class 'Bill' should contain a list which can include Drinks as well as LotteryTickets,
 for which the total can be calculated and the Customer has to be able to make such a bill.
The Customer class also needs a method which confirms the purchase and checks if the numbers on his
LottoryTicket are different for every Ticket he bought. Because when he has the same number on 2 tickets
The confirmation fails.

Answer (score 2):

While indeed not recommended (because it implies a design flaw - you don't know if you have the subclass at hand, but you're still interested in calling its methods), here are some options:

```
trait A {
  // pattern-match to doStuff only if B:
  this match {
    case b: B => b.doStuff()
    case _ => // do nothing
  }

  // check if type is B (not recommended)
  if (this.isInstanceOf[B]) {
    this.asInstanceOf[B].doStuff()
  }
}

class B extends A {
  def doStuff() {}
}
```

Comment: So and where here exactly in trait A are you accessing a field of B? (Please don't even try)

Comment: oops - misread the question - still possible though... updated

Comment: Alright so what i wanted to achieve is not good, so i wrote an example of what i actually want to do. Is this possible on a easy way?

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not available in the principle of object oriented programming. May be if you have to over code make another special price abstract field to work around. Other than that you have to instantiate the sub class in the base class in order to make the fields in the sub class accessible. I don't know if this will help you but if you can post some kind of structure of your classes and what you are trying to do. I think it will help a lot.

Comment: I will add an example

Answer (score 0):

Not without resorting to very dirty tricks, which I would strongly recommend against. It looks like your class hierarchy may have some problems - without specific examples it's hard to give exact advice, but I would in Scala primarily look at composition with traits rather than inheritance. For your problem, you could make a trait for everything that can be dropped in a shopping cart

```
trait Buyable {
  def price: Int
}
```

and then mix that trait in into anything that you want to be able to land in a shopping cart. In that way, you can build small inheritance trees of all sorts of products and just add the trait. For example

```
class Drink extends Buyable {
  // Drink can set the price for all its subclasses
  override def price = ...
}

abstract class LotteryTicket extends Buyable {
  // LotteryTicket cannot, so it's abstract
}
class SilverTicket {
  override def price = 20
}
```

Your shopping cart is oblivious, just operates on Buyable stuff:

```
class ShoppingCart {
  def add(b: Buyable) ...
}
```

Of course, you could also move some identifier, etcetera, to `Buyable`, just like you need it.

Comment: Well i am making some kind of shop which has different items. So i have a class called item (with a field: price) and the different items are object because they only have a price and nothing else. But there are also some special items where every instance of the item has a different id. And a "shopper" must be able to make a "shopping list" of items both normal and special ones, where the total price can be calculated but you must also be able to see the id's of the special items from within the list.